# Let L be a linear transformation defined by its standard matrix AL

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&1&2\\2&-2&3&4\end{bmatrix}$

As I understand domain and codomain of L are $L:\mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ ?

How can I write formula definition of transformation L? I know it should look like $L(x,y,z,t) = (\ldots, \ldots,)$.

I'm not sure how to approach this problem. Could anyone explain how to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Is this the matrix with respect to standard ordered basis of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: the domain of $L$ is $\mathbb{R}^4$

Answer (score 3):

See that :
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&1&2\\2&-2&3&4\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\\t\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x-y+z+2t\\2x-2y+3z+4t\end{bmatrix}$$

$f:\mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$ is given by $f(x,y,z,t)=(x-y+z+2t,2x-2y+3z+4t)$

Comment: Hi ! I hope user3055172 means the matrix with respect to standard ordered basis.

Comment: @Debashish:  As some one would say **unless otherwise specified, we assume that...** :D

Comment: ya ! we have to !!

Comment: I'm not sure - $L(x,y,z,t) = (x, z)$ ?

Comment: no..no... why do you think so?

Comment: Because x and z are independent columns in the matrix. Could you explain it to me, or better give a hint?

Comment: you find linear transformation from a matrix by multiplying that matrix with a general element....

Answer (score 0):

You have to show that in this matrix the second and the fourth column are linear dependent by the first, but not the third.

Indeed

-1*(1,2)=(-1,-2)

and

2*(1,2)=(2,4),

but

h*(1,2)+k*(1,3)=0 ===> h+k=0 & 2h+3k=0 ===> h=k=0.

Comment: Ok, so if they're dependent, we leave only independent (first and third) so formula looks like $L(x,y,z,t) = (x, z)$, yes?

Comment: The formula is L(x,y,z,t)=(x-y+z+2t,2x-2y+3z+4t). What I have written above shows that the rank of the matrix is 2 and so that the codomain is $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.